# Match everything but the following regex? How can I go about this?

Tags: java, regex, string, unit-testing, match

I'm using this REGEX which selects the part (2017-03-06T17:32:33.618) which I need to ignore while matching: `\d{4}(-)\d{2}(-)\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}`.

I used all possible combination to get that "Match everything but the following Regex" result I need. But I can't seem to get it working.

```
 String test =
            " drawId, MIN(draw.draw_date_time) nearestFeatureDraw FROM draw WHERE draw.draw_date_time > " +
            "'2017-03-06T17:32:33.618' GROUP BY draw.lottery_info_id ) nearestDraw on nearestDraw.lotto_id = li.id  " +
            "WHERE 1 = 1 AND li.id = 3  AND lower(li.name) LIKE '%blablabla%' " +
            "ORDER BY jackPot DESC ORDER BY nearestFeatureDraw DESC ";

    boolean pleaseBeTrue = test.matches("Input your Regex here please, and return True");

    System.out.println(pleaseBeTrue);
```

I would appreciate your help to get the right Regex to match everything but that exact DateTime.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but sounds like you could have a capturing group for everything up to the date pattern and then for everything after. The two together is all the non-date text. Of course this wouldn't work if there could be multiple dates in your input.

Answer (score 0):

Make a temporary variable `temp` that does not contain the timestamp, then invoke the `matches()` method on it:

```
String temp = test.replaceAll("\\d{4}(-)\\d{2}(-)\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{3}", "");

boolean pleaseBeTrue = temp.matches("Input your Regex here please, and return True");
```